# Google ortools CVRP - different distance matrix by vehicle

Tags: python, or-tools

In ortools, I know you can run the CVRP with different capacities per vehicle.  However, can you pass a different distance matrix based upon the vehicle?  For example, two cities may be 1000 miles apart, but it may be much faster to get there by airplane than by automobile, so in doing CVRP work I may wish to pass a time matrix, not an actual distance matrix.  That time matrix would be different based upon the vehicle type.

Comment: related?: https://groups.google.com/g/or-tools-discuss/c/rI3aKhh8DOw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be close to this:

```py
callback_indices = []
for vehicle_idx in range(data['n_vehicles']):
    def vehicle_callback(from_index, to_index, i=vehicle_idx):
        from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
        to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
        return data['vehicle_costs'][i] * data['time_matrices'][i][from_node][to_node]
    callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(vehicle_callback)
    callback_indices.append(callback_index)


routing.AddDimensionWithVehicleTransits(
    callback_indices,
    0,
    max,
    False,
    'DimensionName')
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Mizuk. It is very clear now.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass a vector/list of evaluators.

Here is the [C++ API](http://google.github.io/or-tools/cpp_routing/classoperations__research_1_1RoutingModel.html#a66b87fec514d648c751ad9d4df09d05b)/